# cxf jaxrs equivalent of jersey @NameBinding

Tags: jakarta-ee, cxf, jax-rs, servlet-filters, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey with `ContainerRequestFilter & ContainerResponseFilter` with `@NameBinding.`

Now I need to consume SOAP services at server side and I am using cxf (Camel `CxfEndPoint`) for the same.

The cxf jaxrs libraries are conflicting with Jersey jaxrs. So now I decided to eliminate Jersey and would like to use cxf jaxrs for REST services.

Please let me know what is the equivalent of `@NameBinding` with `Filters` in cxf jaxrs. Thanks

Comment: Later versions of cxf (that support JAX-RS 2) will have those classes and annotation. These classes are standard JAX-RS classes, and not implementation specific. CXF 3.x.x for sure. 2.7.x maybe (I don't really use cxf, but could easily check the jar - jaxrs api jar dependency).

Comment: Please add this in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later versions of cxf (that support JAX-RS 2) will have those classes and annotation. These classes are standard JAX-RS classes, and not implementation specific. CXF 3.x.x for sure. 2.7.x maybe (I don't really use cxf, but could easily check the jar - jaxrs api jar dependency)

Note: CXF 2.7.x support JAX-RS 2, but it uses a milestone API dependency. Some of the classes are not there that are in the final 2.0 spec, and some class are there that are not in the final spec. So it's not fully compliant. That's why I said *maybe* (and could easily be checked). CXF 3.x.x is fully compliant with JAX-RS 2.0